# Splitting complex string using Regular Expression

Tags: regex, oracle

I have this string which i need to split using Oracle `Regexp_substr`

The String is like

```
"123456","4,5,6","Hi This is "Sample" String",12345,022222
```

I need to split this string as

```
"123456"
"4,5,6"
"Hi This is "Sample" String"
12345
022222
```

I tried using the following logic Tried to extract string using `",` as delimiter followed by `,` as delimiter, bur when I use `REGEXP_(string,'".*",',1,1)` then it turns the string into

```
"123456","4,5,6","Hi This is "Sample" String",
```

since REGEXP are greedy expression.

How do I achieve my end result?

Comment: `".*?"` should solve this specific problem of greediness.  the '?' makes it match reluctantly.  Still doesn't quite do what your asking, but not quite sure what to make of the nested quotes, and what not.  Maybe `(".*?"|[^"]*?)(,|$)`

Answer (score 1):

Well, you would have to access capture group 2 to get the first match (or just strip off the quotes if they exist):

```
(?:^("*)(.+?)\1(?=,))|(?:(?<=,").+?(?=",))|(?:(?<=,)[^"]+?(?=,|$))
```

Answer (score 1):

This one works for your examples:

`(".+?"(?=,))|\w+`