# Regex to extract csv line contents

Tags: regex, csv

can someone please help me out with a regex statement to achieve the following;

[Example csv line]

```
AAAAA,"BB B",CCCC,,"DDDD,DD DD",EEEEE
```

Expected matches;

```
AAAAA
BB B
CCCC
<empty value>
DDDD,DD DD
EEEEE
```

Comment: Have a look here and see if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21707758/splitting-complex-string-using-regular-expression/21708432#21708432

Comment: This is not a job for regexp. Almost every modern language has a CSV module that will parse it properly. We might even suggest some if you tag with the language you're using. See "XY Problem": "Can someone help me how to chop onions with ice-cream scoop?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're best off not creating your own CSV parser, rather use a premade one such as this:

https://code.google.com/p/csharp-csv-reader/

Any reason why you wouldn't want to do this? If there's a valid one I can produce some regex, but it's not recommended as the format of the input data may change slightly and the match wouldn't happen.

Comment: I'd assumed that there would be a problem with most libraries interpreting some values being enclosed in quotes whilst others weren't. I'll try the one you've suggested first and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Just an update to let everyone know the package dealt with non-consistent quotations around fields fine.

Comment: @Brian Scott - Good job. I deleted my regex post since thats not what you needed.